# Connect Intellij to Docker Daemon - TLS Settings Failed

Tags: tls, intellij-idea, daemon, docker-for-windows

I am trying to connect Intellij to Docker Daemon on Windows 10. I don't want to expose Daemon without TLS, so I have been looking for a way to setup TLS.

I have looked through some documents, including [Windows - Configure Docker Daemon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon) and [Docker Security](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/). But things didn't go as easy as the documents appear.

So first of all, I cannot find a way to use dockerd CLIs. It seems that Docker for Windows does not support 'dockerd'.

Second, I have tried to setup TLS by modifying the daemon configuration file: \.docker\daemon.json. But Docker cannot find my server-cert.pem and server-key.pem

The logs are as follows:

(1)docker + /usr/local/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --config-file /run/config/docker/daemon.json '--swarm-default-advertise-addr=eth0' --userland-proxy-path /usr/bin/vpnkit-expose-port

(2)docker failed to create API server: Could not load X509 key pair (cert: "C:\ProgramData\docker\certs.d\server-cert.pem", key: "C:\ProgramData\docker\certs.d\server-key.pem"): open C:\ProgramData\docker\certs.d\server-cert.pem: no such file or directory

I can find and open the two .pem files on terminal, so I don't understand why docker says 'no such file or directory'.

This is my first time using Docker, so there's no legacy env var or setting that can have a negative impact on Docker.

I have searched a lot but no clue, so I come here asking for help. :)